# Ansible URI SSL Certificate Passphrase

Tags: ansible, ssl-certificate

I have a password protected certificate key that I'm trying to use with the uri module in ansible against a URL that has been configured with 2 way trust.

With curl, I would run `curl -s --cert key.pem:password url`.

In ansible, I can't seem to figure out how to provide the password to the `client_key` option for the `uri` module.

Comment: Using `uri` module is not possible. You can remove the passphrase of the cert key, check https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO5292.html

Comment: Do not put passwords in a command line. Command lines are public (see `ps -ef`). If you put the password in the command line, the password is also public. Public passwords are useles. You can remove them.

Comment: Maybe a custom ansible module would do but I'm still searching for a python 2 code that does the job. With Ansible it prompts for password, we don't provide them. Not sure how to do without prompt.

Answer (score 0):

@ceving, you are missing the point. Sure providing a password on the command line is not ideal, but using passwordless private keys is just as bad. The OP is asking on how ansible uri should do this, but it doesn't. And it should be able to, would have been nice if it did. Why? Because you can encrypt it with ansible vault, OR, you can pass it pass it as an ENV var, could pass it to curl as well, and the ps -ef command wouldn't show it. Or you could have a third party secret management tool like Hashicorp Vault.

To the OP:

uri module doesn't do this, obviously, but you can call curl from ansible with the shell module.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29869156)